# HP LoadRunner question - content checking: web apps only

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I know there some experienced loadRunner users around so I would like to ask (as I was not able to find the answer on my own): Is the content checking available only for webpages? I mean, I cannot check for content in win32 apps, right? Thank you!

Comment: Please explain a little more in detail what you are having difficulty with. It is unclear what protocol you are using, how you record the app and if possible please post snippets of your code so we can "see" what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about using the web_reg_save_param function, then, yes, it is limited to web applications.

Generally, functions with a "web" prefix are unique to web applications.

Answer (score 0):

web_reg_save is web protocol-only, yes.

Depending on the protocol you use, you surely have a way to do a context verification. For example, when you are using terminal emulator, you can check for specific strings in specific display areas. Or, when using Citrix, you can wait for specific bitmaps to appear in certain areas. Or, with RMI, you can inspect whatever you want in the replies you receive.

Inspecting a Win32 app's screen, however, might be painful. LoadRunner tries to "sniff" at the protocol level, so usually you'd have some traffic to emulate on the sockets level, for example. You could still find the app's window handle and fetch some content from it using Windows API calls. LR will not assist you in doing so, though, except for with DLL support.